# Using net group to add users to a AD group

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to add users to the an Active Directory group using net group. We use Domain Local groups for everything. When I go to run the command net group "group name" "username" /add /domain it returns "The group name could not be found. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2220."

If I create a Global group and try to add them it works without issues. I would rather not re-do all of our groups just to be able to use this to add people to a group. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're so close... >smile<

You're looking for the following command to manipulate domain local group membership.

```
NET LOCALGROUP "group name" username /ADD /DOMAIN
```

You can run that from a DC or a member computer in the domain.

BTW, if your domain functional level is Windows 2000 or higher you can change groups freely between the various types w/o having to recreate them.